# SimpleJdbcCall is returning null

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I have the code below which is trying to call a stored procedure rp_report. But it is returning null pointer exception. See the logs and code below for more information. 

I suspect that the error is in the input parameters with type as a LocalDate. But I can't find any logs that indicate why this error is happening. This application is using SpringBoot and SimpleJdbcCall for calling stored procedure.

Greatly appreciate any help.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.octopoda.model.RptByCourier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public class RptByCourierSPRepo {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RptByCourierSPRepo.class);

    @Autowired
    private SimpleJdbcCall spCall;


    public RptByCourier callRptByCourierSP(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate, Integer branchId) {

        logger.info("Initiate Store Procedure rp_report");

        RptByCourier spReturn = new RptByCourier();
        spCall.withCatalogName("dbo"); <----Newly Added
        spCall.withProcedureName("Rp_Report");

        SqlParameterSource sqlParam = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("StartDate", startDate)
                .addValue("EndDate", endDate)
                .addValue("Branch", branchId);


        Map<String, Object> spResult = Objects.requireNonNull(spCall.execute(sqlParam), "spCall.execute() returned null");

/**Setters here Truncated*/
        return spReturn;
    }
}
```

Truncated Logs

```
2017-03-14 14:27:54.291 DEBUG 8592 --- [           main] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source
2017-03-14 14:27:54.384  INFO 8592 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-03-14 14:27:54.400 DEBUG 8592 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [server.ports] PropertySource with highest search precedence
2017-03-14 14:27:54.400  INFO 8592 --- [           main] org.octopoda.Octopoda              : Started Octopoda in 6.652 seconds (JVM running for 7.188)
2017-03-14 14:28:48.742 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.744  INFO 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.744  INFO 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-03-14 14:28:48.744 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'multipartResolver'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.744 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Using MultipartResolver [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver@3aea852b]
2017-03-14 14:28:48.745 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.748 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.749 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.749 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate LocaleResolver with name 'localeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver@41cc2514]
2017-03-14 14:28:48.750 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.755 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.755 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.755 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate ThemeResolver with name 'themeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver@2c1b9387]
2017-03-14 14:28:48.755 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'requestMappingHandlerMapping'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.755 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'viewControllerHandlerMapping'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.755 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'beanNameHandlerMapping'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.755 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'resourceHandlerMapping'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.755 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'defaultServletHandlerMapping'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.755 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'faviconHandlerMapping'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.756 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.756 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'httpRequestHandlerAdapter'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.756 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'simpleControllerHandlerAdapter'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.756 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'errorAttributes'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.756 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'handlerExceptionResolver'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.756 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.759 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.759 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.759 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate RequestToViewNameTranslator with name 'viewNameTranslator': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@63299382]
2017-03-14 14:28:48.759 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'beanNameViewResolver'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.759 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'mvcViewResolver'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.759 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'defaultViewResolver'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.759 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'viewResolver'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.760 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.766 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.766 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.766 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate FlashMapManager with name 'flashMapManager': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@13233d1e]
2017-03-14 14:28:48.766 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'dispatcherServlet' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcherServlet]
2017-03-14 14:28:48.766  INFO 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 22 ms
2017-03-14 14:28:48.766 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Servlet 'dispatcherServlet' configured successfully
2017-03-14 14:28:48.785 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@37efd08a
2017-03-14 14:28:48.787 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/v1/viewCourierReport]
2017-03-14 14:28:48.792 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /v1/viewCourierReport
2017-03-14 14:28:48.796 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.octopoda.model.RptByCourier org.octopoda.rest.RptByCourierRest.viewRptByCourier(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer)]
2017-03-14 14:28:48.796 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'rptByCourierRest'
2017-03-14 14:28:48.796 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/v1/viewCourierReport] is: -1
2017-03-14 14:28:48.827  INFO 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.octopoda.rest.RptByCourierRest   : Starting Rest API --- view report by courier
2017-03-14 14:28:48.828  INFO 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.octopoda.rest.RptByCourierRest   : Start date:2015-01-01 End Date: 2015-01-02 Branch: 213
2017-03-14 14:28:48.839  INFO 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.octopoda.rest.RptByCourierRest   : Converted StartDate: 2015-01-01 Converted EndDate: 2015-01-01
2017-03-14 14:28:48.854  INFO 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.f.o.repository.RptByCourierSPRepo      : Initiate Store Procedure Rp_Report
2017-03-14 14:28:48.856 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall      : JdbcCall call not compiled before execution - invoking compile
2017-03-14 14:28:48.868 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-03-14 14:28:48.869 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=Test]
2017-03-14 14:28:49.625 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.j.c.m.CallMetaDataProviderFactory    : Using org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.SqlServerCallMetaDataProvider
2017-03-14 14:28:49.625 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.j.c.metadata.CallMetaDataProvider    : Retrieving metadata for null/null/Rp_Report
2017-03-14 14:28:49.668 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.j.c.metadata.CallMetaDataProvider    : Retrieved metadata: @RETURN_VALUE 5 4 int false
2017-03-14 14:28:49.668 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.j.c.metadata.CallMetaDataProvider    : Retrieved metadata: @StartDate 1 93 datetime true
2017-03-14 14:28:49.668 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.j.c.metadata.CallMetaDataProvider    : Retrieved metadata: @EndDate 1 93 datetime true
2017-03-14 14:28:49.668 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.j.c.metadata.CallMetaDataProvider    : Retrieved metadata: @Branch 1 4 int true
2017-03-14 14:28:49.668 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-03-14 14:28:49.669 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.j.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext  : Bypassing metadata return parameter for '@RETURN_VALUE'
2017-03-14 14:28:49.669 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.j.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext  : Added metadata in parameter for 'StartDate'
2017-03-14 14:28:49.669 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.j.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext  : Added metadata in parameter for 'EndDate'
2017-03-14 14:28:49.669 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.j.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext  : Added metadata in parameter for 'Branch'
2017-03-14 14:28:49.669 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall      : Compiled stored procedure. Call string is [{call Rp_Report(?, ?, ?)}]
2017-03-14 14:28:49.670 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall      : SqlCall for procedure [Rp_Report] compiled
2017-03-14 14:28:49.671 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.j.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext  : Matching [EndDate, StartDate, Branch] with [StartDate, Branch, EndDate]
2017-03-14 14:28:49.671 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.j.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext  : Found match for [StartDate, EndDate, Branch]
2017-03-14 14:28:49.673 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall      : The following parameters are used for call {call Rp_Report(?, ?, ?)} with {StartDate=org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameterValue@19fe94e7, EndDate=org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameterValue@774c5ba3, Branch=org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameterValue@391238a8}
2017-03-14 14:28:49.673 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall      : 1: StartDate, SQL type 93, type name null, parameter class [org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter]
2017-03-14 14:28:49.673 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall      : 2: EndDate, SQL type 93, type name null, parameter class [org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter]
2017-03-14 14:28:49.673 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall      : 3: Branch, SQL type 4, type name null, parameter class [org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter]
2017-03-14 14:28:49.673 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Calling stored procedure [{call Rp_Report(?, ?, ?)}]
2017-03-14 14:28:49.674 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2017-03-14 14:28:49.674 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=Test]
2017-03-14 14:28:49.715 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils      : Overriding type info with runtime info from SqlParameterValue: column index 1, SQL type -151, type name null
2017-03-14 14:28:49.718 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils      : Overriding type info with runtime info from SqlParameterValue: column index 2, SQL type -151, type name null
2017-03-14 14:28:49.719 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils      : Overriding type info with runtime info from SqlParameterValue: column index 3, SQL type 4, type name null
2017-03-14 14:28:49.934 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : CallableStatement.execute() returned 'true'
2017-03-14 14:28:49.934 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : CallableStatement.getUpdateCount() returned -1
2017-03-14 14:28:49.935 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Added default SqlReturnResultSet parameter named '#result-set-1'
2017-03-14 14:28:49.936 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : CallableStatement.getUpdateCount() returned -1
2017-03-14 14:28:49.937 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils      : Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-03-14 14:28:49.937  INFO 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.f.o.repository.RptByCourierSPRepo      : ======Contents of SP Report by Courier=========
2017-03-14 14:28:49.937  INFO 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.f.o.repository.RptByCourierSPRepo      : Key: #result-set-1 Value: []
2017-03-14 14:28:49.939 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.octopoda.model.RptByCourier org.octopoda.rest.RptByCourierRest.viewRptByCourier(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer)]: java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-03-14 14:28:49.941 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.octopoda.model.RptByCourier org.octopoda.rest.RptByCourierRest.viewRptByCourier(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer)]: java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-03-14 14:28:49.941 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [public org.octopoda.model.RptByCourier org.octopoda.rest.RptByCourierRest.viewRptByCourier(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer)]: java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-03-14 14:28:49.946 DEBUG 8592 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Could not complete request

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.octopoda.repository.RptByCourierSPRepo.callRptByCourierSP(RptByCourierSPRepo.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.octopoda.repository.RptByCourierSPRepo$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c2845390.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
```

This is the line where it mentions the line of code with an error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.fedex.octopoda.repository.RptByCourierSPRepo.callRptByCourierSP(RptByCourierSPRepo.java:66) ~[classes/:na]

spReturn.setPodsCompleted(String.valueOf(spResult.get("PODsCompleted").toString())); <--- line 66
```

Here is my SQL Server Stored Procedure it works in SQL Server if I run it like this

```
rp_report '2015-01-01','2015-01-02',213

Rp_Report (StartDate, EndDate, Branch)
where
StartDate is datetime
EndDate is datetime
Branch is int
```

Added Configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("org.octopoda")
public class OctopodaConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=Test");
        dataSource.setUsername("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbc(DataSource datasource) {

        return new SimpleJdbcCall(datasource);
    }
```

Added the line below and its now asking that there is no input for StartDate parameter

```
spCall.withCatalogName("dbo");
```

## Error log 2

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{call dbo.rp_report()}]; SQL state [S0004]; error code [201]; Procedure or function 'rp_report' expects parameter '@StartDate', which was not supplied.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Procedure or function 'rp_report' expects parameter '@StartDate', which was not supplied.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
```

Comment: I don't know what `@Autowired` means, but could it be `spCall` isn't initialised?

Comment: @axel autowired is a spring annotation to wire up beans and yes it is initialized no problem with the part.

Comment: Then it would certainly help if you make sure where exactly the exception is thrown, for example by using `Objects.requireNonNull` like this: `Map<String, Object> spResult = Objects.requireNonNull(spCall.execute(sqlParam), "spCall.execute() returned null")`, if your logs don't show the line numbers.

Comment: @axel, updated the code as you have suggested but still couldn't find the part where it mentioneds spCall.execute.... but i have updated the logs and placed the line where the error is mentioned.

Comment: Well, that: `String.valueOf(spResult.get("PODsCompleted").toString())` makes no sense. You should use `String.valueOf(spResult.get("PODsCompleted"))` instead.

Comment: @axel yeah i removed it... i forgot to remove that part previously it was a Float but I converted it to String... anyway I added line... see my update it seems to be calling the stored procedure now. however there is another error and it's saying that I didn't give any input parameter for '@StartDate'. Any idea?

Comment: Just to throw out something here. Do you provide a StartDate? If so, have you then tried to remove that variable in the call and see that it works without StartDate and presumably then EndDate with just Branch. This might eliminate some potential error sources (the 2 date fields). Modifying the sp.

Comment: @dimas Ok, then the Java part seems to works now. Sorry, I can't help with spring.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys, I am not able to work out a solution from the error i posted. However I was able to complete my mini project using JDBC Callable Statement which worked perfectly and is way easier to implement.